# Storing bmp filename into an array

Tags: c, arrays, bmp

I have to store the bmp filename in an array. 
eg: files in the current directory
        `a.bmp b.bmp c.txt d.bmp xyz.exe ...`
Currently my output is:

```
fname[0]=.
fname[1]=..  
fname[2]=a.bmp
fname[3]=b.bmp
fname[4]=c.txt
fname[5]=d.bmp
fname[6]=xyz.exe
```

desired output:

```
fname[0]=a.bmp
fname[1]=b.bmp
fname[2]=d.bmp
```

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char filename[20][256];
DIR *dir;
int i=0,k;
struct dirent *ent;
dir = opendir ("D:\\font\\");

if (dir != NULL)
{
/* print all the files and directories within directory */
while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
    {
     strcpy(filename[i],ent->d_name);
    i++;
    /* save filenames in the array */
    }
closedir (dir);
}

for (k=0;k<i;k++) 
  printf("%s\t %d\n",filename[k],k);

FILE *fp;
if(!(fp=fopen(filename[i],"rb")))
{
    //file handling
}
fclose(fp);
     return 0;
}
```

However, this code save all the files of current directory in the array. Could someone help me out how to store only bmp filename in the array?

Comment: You have to add checks for `.` and `..`, as well as any file not ending in `.bmp`.

Comment: In fact, it might be better for you to use [`glob`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check `ent->d_name` before adding to your array. You can do in your `while` loop using [strrchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strrchr/) and [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) for example

```
char *pdot = strrchr(ent->d_name, '.');
if (dot && !strcmp(pdot, ".bmp")) {
    strcpy(filename[i], ent->d_name);
    i++;
}
```

Also if you need case case-insensitive string comparisons use [strcasecmp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strcasecmp.html) instead of `strcmp`

Comment: strcmp is case sensitive - not all bitmap files are ending with lowercase 'bmp'.

Comment: @Constantin You are absolutely right. In this case one need to use your example with strcasecmp() function. Let's my answer be yet another solution with strrchr() function. Or I can change it if you dont mind

Answer (score 0):

try using strstr function; here is a [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) for it.

```
char* str2 = ".bmp";

strstr(filename[i],str2);
```

This will return NULL for all filenames you don't care about.

This will work only if the file names are in the form of  `*.*` .

Comment: This assumes filenames will only contain '.bmp' at the end.

Comment: well that is the question - how to store only the .bmp files. For all other files you will get a null pointer.

Comment: strstr is also case sensitive - not all bitmap files are ending with lowercase 'bmp'

Comment: You would not want to store a file called 'foo.bmp.bar'.

Comment: Fair point, but I do base my solution on the fact that the filenames are in the form of "*.*". For the general case you would have to write a custom function and not use a library one.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing `filename[i]` at a position, where you haven't copied anything at position i (`fopen` line, but increased recently at the `strcpy` line). Be carefull (I commented the affected code out).

To compare the sufix of your c-strings you could use `strcmpi()` if available (it's not part of ISO-C), but because you're using dirent already which is not part of ISO-C also (but in the POSIX) you probably want to use [strcasecmp()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strcasecmp.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char filename[20][256];
  DIR *dir;
  int i=0,k;
  struct dirent *ent;
  dir = opendir ("D:\\font\\");
  if (dir != NULL){
    /* print all the files and directories within directory */
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL){
      size_t offset = strlen(ent->d_name)-4;
      if((strlen(ent->d_name) >= 4) && (!strcasecmp(ent->d_name[offset], ".bmp"))){
        strcpy(filename[i],ent->d_name);
        i++;
        /* save filenames in the array */
      }
    }
    closedir (dir);
  }
  for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    printf("%s\t %d\n",filename[k],k);
  }
  /*FILE *fp;
  if(!(fp=fopen(filename[i],"rb"))){
    //file handling
  }
  fclose(fp);*/
  return 0;
}
```